# loop file_get_contents X times in php

Tags: php, loops, file-get-contents

I have this php code:

```
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/);
```

and I want to ask how many times (input HTML)  to repeat code and start (button HTML) doing it .

I am asking for both HTML code and php code.

I should use for-each or loop?

I search a lot and didn't find any answer.

I tried this for-each :

```
foreach (array_chunk($list, 4) as $row) {
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/); }
```

Comment: For what reason would you want to iterate the request? Is it's content changing?

Answer (score -1):

i found it :

```
$i = 0;
$times_to_run = 5;  // 5 times repeat
$array = array();
while ($i++ < $times_to_run)
{
    file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/);

}
```